# When connecting to a server farm in sharepoint foundation 2013, we are getting cannot create new farm error: One or more types failed to load

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, server-farm

When trying to create a new server farm in the sharepoint foundation 2013 we get a following error :

```
The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-SPConfigurationDatabase

    cmdlet New-SPConfigurationDatabase at command pipeline position 1
    Supply values for the following parameters:
    DatabaseName: SharePoint_Config
    DatabaseServer: PC78\SQLEXPRESS,25111
    FarmCredentials
    Passphrase: *********
    New-SPConfigurationDatabase : One or more types failed to load. Please refer
    to the upgrade log for more details.
    At line:1 char:1
    + New-SPConfigurationDatabase
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:
       SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase) [New-SPConfigurationDatabase], SPUpgra
      deException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPCon
       figurationDatabase
```

And the error log is shown below :

```
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: One or more types failed to load. 
Please refer to the upgrade log for more details.     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionByMajorVersion(Type typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.get_CurrentSPSiteWssTargetSchemaVersion()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPContentDatabase database, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, Strin... b712a522-fa85-49eb-b59c-dedf55295504
        ...g secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, String quotaTemplate, String sscRootWebUrl, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName, Boolean overrideCompatibilityRestriction)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.CreateDefaultInstance(SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, SPWebService adminService, IdentityType identityType, ... b712a522-fa85-49eb-b59c-dedf55295504
     ...String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CreateAdministrationWebService(SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CreateBasicServices(SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuil... b712a522-fa85-49eb-b59c-dedf55295504
            ...der configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase.InternalProcessRecord()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() b712a522-fa85-49eb-b59c-dedf55295504
Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL b712a522-fa85-49eb-b59c-dedf55295504
 Leaving ProcessRecord Method of New-SPConfigurationDatabase.   e9ae5ba6-c499-0000-d35c-aee999c4cf01
 Entering EndProcessing Method of New-SPConfigurationDatabase.  e9ae5ba6-c499-0000-d35c-aee999c4cf01
 Leaving EndProcessing Method of New-SPConfigurationDatabase.   e9ae5ba6-c499-0000-d35c-aee999c4cf01
 Event 3759 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Error' occurred 1 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log
```

Comment: are you running the windows powershell  or sharepoint powershell, also try Run SharePoint Powershell console as Administrator. Make sure the account under you running the pwoershell should have proper permission on SQL server

Comment: we are running a sharepoint powershellcommand.we has given permission for Securityadmin and  DBcreator roles on SQL Server.

Comment: but Make sure the logged in user who is trying to run SharePoint PowerShell commands is having the right "SharePoint_Shell_Access" to the SharePoint_Configuration database....http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/18/sharepoint-powershell-command-problem-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx

Comment: 1st line in command powershell window is your problem so check my last comment

Comment: cannot find "SharePoint_Shell_Access" followed the link

Comment: try powershell from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517571/powershell-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-a

Comment: we get error:Get-SPDatabase : The term 'Get-SPDatabase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: we even tried powershell cmds to Configuring a new SharePoint farm

Comment: Now I set sharePoint PowerShell commands have the right "SharePoint_Shell_Access" to the SharePoint_Configuration.Still the line at top of sharepoint shell.